# d3 control space between ticks

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way to put more space between ticks?

```
var xAxisScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 87]).range([0, width]);
var XAxis =d3.svg.axis().scale(xAxisScale).orient("bottom").ticks(87).tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
```

I get

```
1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8-- ....
```

but I want more space between ticks. like

```
1----2----3----4----5----6----7----8---- ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do so simply by increasing the value of the variable `width` (in a portion of code which is not shared in your question).

If you do not want to change the value of `width`, just specify a value directly inside `.range`.

Example:

```
var xAxisScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 87]).range([0, 960]);
```

Comment: Is there other way except for changing the width value?